Use Kotlin Multiplatform wasmJS in android/ios webview
Is it possible to use Kotlin Multiplatform's wasmJS in a WebView?
I've configured it for Android's WebView, but the screen remains blank.
However, when using the IR (JavaScript) target, it works fine.
This is my implementations in kotlin android
@Composable
fun WebViewScreen(url: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var isLoading: Boolean by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val webView = remember {
        WebView(context).apply {
            webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                    isLoading = true
                }

                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                    isLoading = false
                }

                override fun onReceivedError(
                    view: WebView?,
                    request: WebResourceRequest?,
                    error: WebResourceError?
                ) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "${error?.description}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                    view: WebView?,
                    request: WebResourceRequest?
                ): Boolean = false
            }

            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
            settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        }
    }

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            webView.destroy()
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color(0xFF152132))
            .systemBarsPadding()
    ) {
        if (isLoading) {
            LinearProgressIndicator(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                color = Color(0XFF40BED0)
            )
        }
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            factory = { webView },
            update = { it.loadUrl(url) }
        )
    }
}

